# PDO execute() error with bindParam

Tags: php, pdo, bindparam

I can not found where is my fail with this code

```
 $username = $_POST["UserID"];
 $password = $_POST["PWD"];
 $sql = 'select COUNT(*) from Staff where UserID = :UserID and PWD = :PWD';
 $result = $cnnEmployee->prepare($sql);
 $result->bindParam(':UsedID',$username, PDO::PARAM_STR)
 $result->bindParam(':PWD',$password, PDO::PARAM_STR)
 $result->execute(); //Error here: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'
```

But if I change to

```
 $username = $_POST["UserID"];
 $password = $_POST["PWD"];
 $sql = 'select COUNT(*) from Staff where UserID = :UserID and PWD = :PWD';
 $result = $cnnEmployee->prepare($sql);
 $result->execute(array(':UserID'=>$username, ':PWD'=>$password));
```

it work fine
Pls help me to find where is my problem.

Comment: You noticed the typo with `:UsedID` instead of `:UserID` in the first example?

Comment: Oh, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When you're binding the parameters you use `:UsedID` but the placeholder in the query is looking for `:UserID`